# Why didn't the Greeks spoil Red heifer ashes?

Tags: chanuka, parah-adumah

IIRC, as the Chanukkah story goes, the Greeks entered the Temple and defiled all the oil needed for lighting the Menorah.

Why didn't the Greeks spoil [Red heifer ashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_heifer), as it, seemingly, is far more mattering, valuable and rare?

(*This is my Chevrutah's question, I didn't' think of it*)

Comment: If you came to ransack my house, would you touch the food or the mothballs?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't understand the metaphor. I think it's logical that the enemy would seek the highest impact.

Comment: Highest impact for their supplies gathering. Indeed!

Comment: The ashes seem to have been kept in multiple places throughout the land, not only at the Beit HaMikdash

Comment: @DoubleAA Oh, I get it now. But the narrative IIRC was always about them trying to hurt the Temple functions, not just looting it, isn't it so?

Comment: @JoelK Are you sure? I know very little about purity and it always seemed that the Temple is the only place it should be kept. Also, how do you know there were more than one jars?

Comment: @AlBer I have no reason to think one way or another, or certainly that they'd know enough halakha to know how to maximally ruin things. Maybe check Maccabees?

Comment: @DoubleAA I forgot the punchline, it says "וטמאו כל השמנים", not spilled it or grabbed them

Comment: @AlBerko That is the relevant fact for that song. It's not a historical summary of all the events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of it wasn't kept in the Beis Hamikdash and the part that was in the Bais Hamikdash was kept in hidden places.

The Rambam in Hilchas Para Aduma Perek Gimmel says

> אֵין מַכְנִיסִין כְּלוּם מֵאֶפְרָהּ לְהַנִּיחוֹ בָּעֲזָרָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר יט ט) "וְהִנִּיחַ מִחוּץ לַמַּחֲנֶה". וּשְׁלֹשָׁה חֲלָקִים הָיוּ חוֹלְקִין אֶת כָּל אֶפְרָהּ אֶחָד נִתַּן בַּחֵיל וְאֶחָד בְּהַר הַמִּשְׁחָה וְאֶחָד מִתְחַלֵּק לְכָל הַמִּשְׁמָרוֹת. זֶה שֶׁמִּתְחַלֵּק לְכָל הַמִּשְׁמָרוֹת הָיוּ הַכֹּהֲנִים מְקַדְּשִׁין מִמֶּנּוּ. וְזֶה שֶׁנִּתַּן בְּהַר הַמִּשְׁחָה הָיוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל מַזִּין מִמֶּנּוּ. וְזֶה שֶׁנִּתַּן בַּחֵיל הָיָה מוּכָן וּמֻצְנָע שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר יט ט) "וְהָיְתָה לַעֲדַת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל לְמִשְׁמֶרֶת" מְלַמֵּד שֶׁמַּצְנִיעִין מִמֶּנּוּ. וְכֵן הָיוּ מַצְנִיעִין מֵאֵפֶר כָּל פָּרָה וּפָרָה שֶׁשּׂוֹרְפִין בַּחֵיל. וְתֵשַׁע פָּרוֹת אֲדֻמּוֹת נַעֲשׂוּ מִשֶּׁנִּצְטַוּוּ בְּמִצְוָה זוֹ עַד שֶׁחָרַב הַבַּיִת בַּשְּׁנִיָּה. רִאשׁוֹנָה עָשָׂה משֶׁה רַבֵּנוּ. שְׁנִיָּה עָשָׂה עֶזְרָא. וְשֶׁבַע מֵעֶזְרָא עַד חֻרְבַּן הַבַּיִת. 
>   וְהָעֲשִׂירִית יַעֲשֶׂה הַמֶּלֶךְ הַמָּשִׁיחַ מְהֵרָה
>
> *None of its ashes are brought into the Temple Courtyard for storage, as ibid.:9 states: "And he shall place it outside the camp." The ashes were divided into three portions: one was placed in the chayl one, on the Mount of Olives, and one, was divided among all the priestly guardposts.
>   The one that was divided among all the priestly watches was used by the priests to sanctify themselves. The one that was placed on the Mount of Olives was used by the entire Jewish people for sprinkling. And the one that was placed in the chayl was prepared and hidden away, as implied by ibid. which states: "It will be a security for the congregation of Israel." This teaches that it was put away for safekeeping.
>   Indeed, in the chayl, they would put away for safekeeping a portion of the ashes from every red heifer that was burnt*

Comment: Thank you, this might answer the question. However, I still wonder, had they wanted to disrupt the Beis Hamikdosh work shouldn't they be after the ashes instead of the oil?